# Резиновое фоновое изображение

Tags: css

Возможно как-то сделать, чтобы фоновое изображение в блоке div было резиновым, пропорции в процентах не действуют?

Answer (score 2):

Можно, но это относится к css3, и не все браузеры это понимают.
[background-size](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size).

Чтобы сделать изображение резиновым, подложите под контент изображение:

```
<div style="height:400px;width:70%;overflow:hidden;position:relative">  
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%" />  
    <div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:1;width:100%;height:100%">content</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Нормальным людям посвящается!

Приём css3:

```
div {
width:1500px;
heigth:200px;
background-image: url(/bg.jpg);
background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
}
```

Что произойдёт?

Браузер запихнёт в такой узко-широкий блок картинку сколь угодно гигантского размера (разумеется,в качестве подложки),так же браузер растянет и масштабирует даже однопиксельную картинку до размеров блока.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ:

Первые 2-а аттрибута задают размеры блока по ширине=1500 пикселов и высоте=200 пикселов,
третий аттрибут-адрес картинки,четвёртый,пятый и шестой аттрибуты-масштабируют картинку по размерам блока div для "w3с-браузеров",для Firefox и для Вебкит-браузеров типа Google Chrome,Apple Safari соответственно.

Comment: Я бы предложил другой порядок правил, а именно:

    div {
      width:1500px;
      heigth:200px;
      background-image: url(/bg.jpg);
      -moz-background-size:cover;
      -webkit-background-size:cover;
      background-size:cover;
    }

Так надежнее.

Answer (score 1):

Если уж использовать имидж как бекграунд, то лучше `background-size:contain`

Comment: Чем вам не нравится? Это ответ!

Comment: @Alex: если считаете ответ плохим — поставьте минус.

Comment: @NickVolynkin для нас это скорее комментарий чем ответ. точно также как и ответы ниже.

Comment: @Alex: ок, понял вас.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

?
Или что вы имете ввиду под резиновым ?

Answer (score 0):

Нормальные люди делают либо изображение, которое можно n-ное количество раз на подложке "повторить", либо яваскриптами получают параметры экрана пользователя, либо кладут div на как подложку и в него уже картинку.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно либо изображение вырезать так чтобы можно было замостить им всю площать контейнера, либо сразу сделать большое изображение (например 1920пх) в ширину из расчета на макимальное разрешение поддерживаемое мониторами пк, а еще лучше не делать резиновых изображений потому что вы не знаете какое разрешение будет у пользователя.